# innerhtml does not work with the long string of html

Tags: javascript, html

```
contactPage.onclick = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < homepages.length; i++) {
            if (homepages[i].classList.contains("current-page")) {
                homepages[i].classList.remove("current-page");
                pageLayout.innerHTML="<div class="contact">
                    < h1 id = "contact-heading" > Contact Form</h1 >

                        <form >
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-25">
                                    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-75">
                                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
            </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-25">
                                        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-75">
                                        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-25">
                                            <label for="country">Country</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-75">
                                            <select id="country" name="country">
                                                <option value="australia">Australia</option>
                                                <option value="canada">Canada</option>
                                                <option value="usa">USA</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-25">
                                            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-75">
                                            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button class="submit-contact">submit</button>
                                </div>   ";
            }
        }
        contactPage.classList.add("current-page");

    }
```

why does this gives me an error and does not allow me to pass this string of html as a substitution for my body container?
Is there a way of passing html in as well to update the page without the reload?
thanks in advance

Comment: In javascript line breaks in quoted strings need to be escaped as do mismatched quotes. Using a template literal would make this work easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided has a lot of syntax errors:

1. double quotes within double quotes must be escaped (with a `\`):

   - wrong: `const someHtml = "<span class="test"/>";`
   - right: `const someHtml = "<span class=\"test\"/>";`
2. similar to the previous point, multiline strings in javascript must be escaped (unless you use string template):

   ```
   // example with string literals
   const html = "<span>\
   some text\
   </span>";

   // example with string template
   const html = `<span>
   some text
   </span>`;
   ```

Side note: avoid using `innerHTML` if possible - it's very resource intensive because the browser needs to parse the string and arbitrarily modify the page structure.

Answer (score 0):

You have `"` in your html, and you're using `"` for your string. This makes javascript confused about where the string ends..

Now there are 2 ways to solve this:

1. Escape all the `"` in your html code
2. Just use a different character for your string

Try this:

```
contactPage.onclick = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < homepages.length; i++) {
            if (homepages[i].classList.contains("current-page")) {
                homepages[i].classList.remove("current-page");
                pageLayout.innerHTML=`<div class="contact">
                    < h1 id = "contact-heading" > Contact Form</h1 >

                        <form >
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-25">
                                    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-75">
                                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
            </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-25">
                                        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-75">
                                        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-25">
                                            <label for="country">Country</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-75">
                                            <select id="country" name="country">
                                                <option value="australia">Australia</option>
                                                <option value="canada">Canada</option>
                                                <option value="usa">USA</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-25">
                                            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-75">
                                            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button class="submit-contact">submit</button>
                                </div>   `;
            }
        }
        contactPage.classList.add("current-page");

    }
```

Comment: this is really good and working except for the h1 which is displayed as a line of code on my webpage, the h1 is not recognized for some reason

Comment: Try removing the space between the < and h1.